# Don't start Xserver

Tags: boot, root, init.d

I'm trying to convince Ubuntu's init system not to start X11 at boot-up. Removing `gdm` did not change the fact that each time the machine restarts, X11 with Gnome comes up.

How do I get rid of it? I need to auto-login as root with no Xserver after startup. It's inteded for a very specific automation-purpose to behave like that and not meant for Desktop experience ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two files controlling X startup in a standard Ubuntu installation: `/etc/init/gdm.conf` and `/etc/init/failsafe-x.conf`.  While the first is owned by package `gdm`, the second is owned by `x11-common` and will be triggered if GDM fails to start, which happens in particular when you remove GDM.

However, you need not remove packages to prevent GDM from starting; it enough to tell the [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) system not to start it:

1. edit the `/etc/init/gdm.conf` and the `/etc/failsafe-x.conf` files (it might be a good idea to make a backup copy of the files before editing)
2. change the existing `start on ...` stanza with a condition that is not met 
   in your standard environment; for instance, you might want to start X only on
   "runlevel 5" which is what other Linux distros traditionally did:

   ```
   start on runlevel [5]
   ```
3. save your changes and restart

Complete documentation on the upstart configuration files can be read by `man 5 init`.

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
sudo update-rc.d -f gdm remove
```

Then to restore:

```
sudo update-rc.d -f gdm default
```

Answer (score 2):

If this is meant for a very specific, non-graphical task, `ubuntu-desktop` is not what you want.

I know you shouldn't need to remove things to stop them running but, frankly, you'd do better to grab the [Ubuntu Server](http://www.ubuntu.com/server) (or even [minimal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD)) CD and start from a low-level.

You're driving a tank to work. You could strip it down, breaking the way it was supposed to work and taking a long time about it... Or you could trade it in for the super-bike equivalent and just install what you need.