# How to make a computer running on runlevel 3 ask for password when waking up from suspend in X?

Tags: xorg, suspend, laptop, security, console

I have recently set [runlevel `3` as a kernel parameter](https://askubuntu.com/a/713637/364819) instead of runlevel `5`, though this has caused a little bit of a problem... Because when I execute `startx` and then once the GUI has loaded, if I close the lid, wait for the right amout of time, or do the keyboard shortcut to suspend, it does, but when it wakes up again it does not ask for a password as it should and did on runlevel `5`, so this is a bit of a security risk. 
How can I get it to ask for a password when waking up from suspend when running on runlevel `3` in X?

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18.

---

This is another of my security worries related to this (I am just linking the question as it is similar): [Can console be suspended and ask for a password on wakeup?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/677651/can-console-be-suspended-and-ask-for-a-password-on-wakeup)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing runlevels is an ***excellent*** method to do a [Root Cause Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_cause_analysis), but hardly a *solution!*

At best, it's a *workaround* and as you noticed, it creates a sleuth of [other problems](https://askubuntu.com/questions/713933/how-to-make-a-computer-running-on-runlevel-3-ask-for-password-when-waking-up-fro), so if you need to disable X, [just do so](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6357/dont-start-xserver) and:

**Please!**

#### Please!

### Please!

## Please!

*Set your runlevel back to 5!*

---

#### Alternatively,

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

and:

1. Change `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=”"` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=”text”` which will force Ubuntu to boot directly into Text Mode.
2. Uncomment `#GRUB_TERMINAL=console` by removing the `#`which will force the grub menu into B&W Text Mode

(credit for the alternative method goes to [@Serg](https://askubuntu.com/users/295286/serg)!

Comment: But I understand from [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/79682/364819) that something additional must be done on systems running systemd rather than upstart.